# VS 2012 include or link image in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2012

I am testing a SW (somekind of graph thing) as part of my university studies and would like the developers' life make easier (and also make them not to be frustrated and lost in the lot of tests). I have ms visio files with the test cases. I export them in PNG and put the PNG in the test directory near the .cs files (and I also put there the test documentation in pdf). I would like to put the image in the source code. I know there is a plugin for VS 2010 but not for 2012 (I need a solution working in both). How can I link files from comments? The problem is that all link should be relative as we work with an svn repo and the local work path is different for everybody. Is there any way to link local files from doc comment? The best would be if the generated documentation contained the images (definetd with relative path). But the best would be is there could be links on the certain parts of the visio files, but I think that this is impossimle.

Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed images files into a Visual Studio project in the Resources section so that they are essentially built into the executable.  Right click the project and goto Properties and then goto Resources and you can drag images into the panel to add them.  You can access them by using `Properties.Resources.imageFile`

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood me: I am looking forward to embed or link images in the SOURCE. Images should not be embedded in the assembly!

Comment: You want to include a hyperlink in a comment in the code file?  and embedding images in the assembly is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes I want include hyperlink in the source. But relative link (ot http:// hyperlink but e.g. ../../Docs/Image.png and it should be clickable). I don't want to embed images in the assembly - I don't need it.

Comment: the link to a local file would be `file:///c:/folder` but I'm not sure if it will work with relative paths.  it probably will somehow